# Cannot locate component from cfinvoke statement

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, cfinvoke

I had some ColdFusion code handed to me due to someone leaving the company that I was tasked to maintain. The problem is the last time I looked at some ColdFusion code was around 10 years ago so I'm completely lost and I'm starting from scratch.

My issue is I'm trying to locate the component or code and whatever is being called in the code shown below.

```
<cfinvoke component="_admin_tools_kms" method="listKMSUsers" returnVariable="getKMSUsers">
    <cfinvokeargument name="argFullAccount" value="1" />
</cfinvoke>
```

I know this is returning a list of users for the system but I cannot locate the exact code making that call. Should that component name, "_admin_tools_kms", be the name of a *cfm* file somewhere or can that be just a reference name created somehow?

Comment: Since the value is a simple string, it's the name of the component file. The actual file name will end with a ".cfc" extension.: _admin_tools_kms.cfc. It's likely to be located in the same directory as the calling file.

Comment: I see Ageax beat me by a minute. You should find `_admin_tools_kms.cfc` in the same folder as the calling cfm.

Comment: Alternately, I would just search for the method name `listKMSUsers`. It's possible that the CFC file being referenced in the `component` attribute  extends or includes other files.

Comment: Someone should write this up as an answer. Sometimes it is hard to find what is calling what.

Answer (score 4):

Let's break this down:

```
<cfinvoke 
    component="someComponent" 
    method="someFunction" 
    returnVariable="someVariable">
    <cfinvokeargument name="someArgument" value="foo" />
</cfinvoke>
```

The attribute `component` is either name of a file with a `.cfc` extension or a variable containing an instance of that component. If it was a variable, it would be referenced as `#someComponent#`.

If there's just a simple value in there, odds are there's a file named `someComponent.cfc` in the same folder.

If there's a dot-separated value in there, like `cfc.services.someComponent`,

- look for a folder at the web root named `/cfc/` that contains another folder `/services/` in which you'll find the file `someComponent.cfc`.
- If you don't see that folder, look for a ColdFusion mapping in the root `Application.cfc` file that creates the alias `cfc` and maps it to the folders you want.
- and if THAT's not there, then check your web server for folder aliases or mappings to see what the heck some psychopath did to hide where that code exists.

BUT, I prefer doing a simple text search for the method referenced instead of the component. That function could exist in another component or file than the one referenced.

Since a CFC can extend another CFC, there could be a `parentComponent.cfc` that `someComponent` extends which actually contains the method in question. Worse, the file `someComponent.cfc` could have other files included where one contains the method. The only downside is if the function is named something common like `create`.